# template<typename T>: only static data member templates are allowed

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, template-variables

```
class value {
    template<typename T> T value_1;
    float value_2;

public:
    template<typename T> void Set1(T first) {
        value_2 = (float)0;
        value_1 = first;
    }

    void Set2(float second) {
        value_2 = second;
    }

    float Get2() {
        return this->value_2;
    }

    template<typename T> T Get1() {
        return value_1;
    }
};
```

`Value_1` gives out an error, saying that only static data member templates are allowed. Is there a way to keep `value_1` without a type?

Comment: Think about this: How would you be able to create an object of this class if `T` is not known? It's not possible. One solution is to make the whole class a template.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The type of a non-static data member must be known. Otherwise, what's `sizeof(value)`?

To store a value of an arbitrary type, you can use [`std::any`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any) or [`boost::any`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/any.html).

Use:

```
class value {
    std::any value_1;
    float value_2;

public:
    template<typename T> void Set1(T first) {
        value_2 = (float)0;
        value_1 = first;
    }

    void Set2(float second) {
        value_2 = second;
    }

    float Get2() {
        return this->value_2;
    }

    template<typename T> T Get1() {
        return std::any_cast<T>(value_1);
    }
};
```